# jQuery Shorter Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code:

```
function showCreatedBy(){
        $(".created-by").css("background-color", "#949494");
        $(".date-time-data").hide();
        $(".reference-data").hide();
        $(".payment-status-data").hide();
        $(".created-by-data").show();
    }
    function showDateTime(){
        $(".date-time").css("background-color", "#949494");
        $(".created-by-data").hide();
        $(".reference-data").hide();
        $(".payment-status-data").hide();
        $(".date-time-data").show();
    }
    function showReference(){
        $(".reference").css("background-color", "#949494");
        $(".created-by-data").hide();
        $(".reference-data").show();
        $(".payment-status-data").hide();
        $(".date-time-data").hide();
    }
    function showPaymentStatus(){
        $(".payment-status").css("background-color", "#949494");
        $(".created-by-data").hide();
        $(".reference-data").hide();
        $(".payment-status-data").show();
        $(".date-time-data").hide();
    }
```

Is there any way to shorten this using jQuery? I don't understand a lot but this seems really redundant to me.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: each of the functions are doing different things, to differing things, so no, there's not much you can do to make it more concise.

Comment: `$(".created-by-data, .reference-data, .date-time-data").hide();`

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217853/how-to-hide-multiple-selectors-as-once-with-jquery) will help you...

Comment: Please show your HTML too. However you should really research the DRY principle

Comment: You should probably toggle a single class on a common parent and do all that visibility and color toggling in CSS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to code review.

Comment: @MarcB well, sort of true, but it's not really _that_ hard to DRY this code. Have a function that accepts a selector, hide all 4, then show the one passed in and set the background. Even though each function does "different things", it's the same pattern every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the name of the functions, you can reduce the code to something like this:

```
function showField(name) {
    $("." + name).css("background-color", "#949494");
    $.each(['created-by-data', 'reference-data', 'payment-status-data', 'date-time-data'], function(i, v) {
        $('.' + v).toggle((name + '-data') == v);
    });
}

showField('payment-status'); // Show only "payment-status"

// showField('created-by-data'); // Show only "created-by-data"

// etc.
```

Comment: Even if changing names of the methods is not an option, it is possible to define `function showPaymentStatus() { showField('payment-status'); }` and so on.

Comment: Probably you may need to change the line $('.' + v ).toggle(name == v); to $('.' + v).toggle((name + '-data') == v);

Comment: @Karpak, right, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

Use `addClass` and `removeClass` instead of assigning CSS styles directly. Lets you change a class without having to touch everything that uses it.

You can create variables to shorten your selectors:

```
var $pmtStatus = jQuery(".payment-status");
```

Or you can do things to more than one item at a time:

```
$(".created-by-data, .reference-data").hide();
```

Something else you might be able to do - is to have a function that hides everything, then only show what you want. Then you don't need to keep track of what to hide.

```
function hideAll() {
    $(".date-time-data").hide();
    $(".reference-data").hide();
    $(".payment-status-data").hide();
    $(".created-by-data").hide();
}

function showPaymentStatus(){
    hideAll();
    $(".payment-status").css("background-color", "#949494");
    $(".payment-status-data").show();
}
```